# Remove controller name and action from custom route

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In Magento 2:

I Want to change this route/URL in myproject 
from
http://myproject.com/customstyle/index/index/parameter/paravalue

to 
http://myproject.com/customstyle/parameter/paravalue

This is a custom Url

I have added the route in XML file i.e routes.xml

```
          <route id="customstyle" frontName="customstyle">
              <module name="modulename"/>
          </route>
```

n i have a layout file customstyle_index_index.xml where the template file is included.

/app/vendor/module/etc/di.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
           <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
               instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation
               ="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">


<type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
  <arguments>
      <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="customstyle" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="class" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Controller\CustomStyle</item>
              <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
              <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">22</item>
          </item>
      </argument>
  </arguments>
 </type>
 </config>
```

Created the app/vendor/module/controller/CustomStyle.php

```
   namespace vendor\module\Controller;

    class CustomStyle implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
    {
        protected $actionFactory;
        protected $_response;
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
        ) {
            $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
            $this->_response     = $response;

        }
        public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
        {

            $identifier  = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
            $identifiers = explode('/', $$identifier);
            if (strpos($identifier, 'customstyle') !== false && count($identifiers) == 3) {
                $request->setModuleName('customstyle')->//module name
                    setControllerName('index')->//controller name
                    setActionName('index')->//action name
                    setParam($identifiers[1], $identifiers[2]); //custom parameters
            } else {
                return false;
            }
            return $this->actionFactory->create(
                'Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward', ['request' => $request]
            );
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve above issue?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146002)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146002)